# MongoClient not found in WAMP

Tags: mongodb, wampserver

I have been trying to run MongoDB on WAMP all day and It shows the error: Fatal Error: MongoClient class not found. I have a windows 64 bit, Wamp 32 bit ( after trying and failing at running wamp 64), MongoDB 64 bit. I downloaded mongo php_driver from https://s3.amazonaws.com/drivers.mongodb.org/php/index.html. Copied php_mongo-1.5.1-5.4-vc9.dll to the php extension folder as php_mongo.dll. Added it as extension in php.ini (configuration setting file). My php.ini extension section looks like this:

```
extension=php_bz2.dll
extension=php_curl.dll
extension=php_com_dotnet.dll
extension=php_fileinfo.dll
extension=php_gd2.dll
extension=php_gettext.dll
extension=php_gmp.dll
extension=php_intl.dll
extension=php_imap.dll
;extension=php_interbase.dll
extension=php_ldap.dll
extension=php_mbstring.dll
extension=php_exif.dll      ; Must be after mbstring as it depends on it
extension=php_mysql.dll
extension=php_mysqli.dll
;extension=php_oci8.dll      ; Use with Oracle 10gR2 Instant Client
;extension=php_oci8_11g.dll  ; Use with Oracle 11gR2 Instant Client
extension=php_openssl.dll
;extension=php_pdo_firebird.dll
extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
;extension=php_pdo_oci.dll
;extension=php_pdo_odbc.dll
;extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlite.dll
;extension=php_pgsql.dll
extension=php_shmop.dll
extension=php_mongo.dll
```

I've reboot the server. I don't see Mongo on the phpinfo() file and also the php error log files shows the following:

```
c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.12/ext/php_intl.dll' - The specified module could not be found.
 PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.12/ext/php_ldap.dll' - %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

`PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: mongo: Unable to initialize module`

Please tell me what I am missing because I have tried everything.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To fix the php_intl.dll error do the following using the wmapmanager menus

```
wampmanager -> Apache -> Version -> and click on the 2.4.9 version number
```

This will cause wampmanager to rebuild all the SYMLINKS in the `\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\bin` folder.

As to the mongo error, are you sure you are editing the correct `php.ini` file.

Again use the wampmanager menu system to edit the correct `php.ini` file

```
wampmanager -> PHP -> php.ini
```

I expect the extension was not added to this file so add

```
extension=php_mongo.dll
```

like you did to the PHP CLI version of the ini file.

Comment: Thank you, the error for php_intl.dll error went away after rebuilding. But is still shows:                                   PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.12/ext/php_mongo.dll' - %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
I have tried many mongo php_drivers and now have the php_mongo-1.5.1-5.4-vc9.dll, but is still doesn't work.

Comment: So apperantly I was just using a wrong mongo php_driver. I downloaded the pacakge php_driver 1.1.5 and tried some of the .dll files. php_mongo-1.5.1-5.5-vc11.dll is working fine for me now. Thank you!

Comment: Gosh!! I don't believe editing the `php.ini` by clicking on `wampmanager` worked!! I wonder where does this `php.ini` reside? I have just one version of php installed and I had already tried editing that file to enable the extension but this answer hinted me to open `ini` file using wampmanager and it didn't have that line!!

Comment: By the way, thanks!! I see that you quite active on wampserver forums also... came across several of your posts there too. Doing a great job, keep it up!