# PHP extensions on Windows 8 (wamp) : confusion: 32 bit or 64 bit

Tags: php, mongodb, windows-8.1, wampserver

I have 32-bit Windows 8.1, processor is x64 Intel Pentium

I am running apache 2.4.9 and php on wampserver
phpinfo: PHP Version 5.5.12 , Architecture  x86, Compiler MSVC11 (Visual C++ 2012)

Trying to install php_mongo.dll

If I use **php_mongo-1.5.5-5.5-vc11-x86_64.dll** I get 0xc000035a windows error,
when i use **php_mongo-1.5.5-5.5-vc11.dll** I get PHP error "*Fatal error: Class 'MongoClient' not found in ...*" and extension php_mongo is marked with exclamation mark in wamp php extensions menu: see picture

[image]

Comment: Is MongoDB installed and running?

Comment: nope, it's not running. Does it matter? emm... trying to run at the moment

Comment: nothing changed when launched mongod and restarted wampserver

Answer (score 3):

OK 
Point 1, If you are running a 32bit Windows as you say then you have to use the 32bit WampServer ( which I assume you did ) and also the 32bit mongo extension.

Point 2, In WAMPServer is you get a Warning symbol like that against a PHP Extension it usually means one of 2 things :-

- You have a dll in the `\ext` folder but no `extension=???` in php.ini to match it.
- You have an `extension=???` in php.ini but no dll in the `\ext` folder that matches it.

If the above info does not solve your issue then, [this recent similiar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25288025/mongoclient-not-found-in-wamp), seems to suggest that the `php_mongo-1.5.1-5.5-vc11.dll` worked for that questioner when the 1.5.5 version did not. I would try that version, remember you will need the Thread Safe version i.e. the file without the `-nts` in its name.

Comment: Point 2: I had both dll and proper ini setting (I checked it few times), and tried all the dll's available despite I knew I should use 32bit as my Windows, thread safe so that it would work fine with apache and compiled with VC11 as my PHP.

So, I migrated to Ubuntu now. Windows sucks.

Comment: That comment reminds me of an old saying we have here :- _A bad workman always blames his tools_

Comment: might be so, but I didn't have much inspiration to gei it all up and running on windows